# Arc style navigation in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a pizza html that has arc style navigation. I made the navigation in image format. but my client says, I need the navigation in jquery. I can't make the navigation in arc style in jquery but I know jquery intermediate level not advance. pls help me.

Comment: Since the current implementation works, please tell us what do you want done in jQuery? Do you want it to insert the nodes? to make the navigation dynamic in terms of menu items, while still retaining it's arc-ness ?

Comment: Wait, your client tells you, the professional, how to do something? Oh, and you can achieve this with CSS3.

Comment: What effect does the client really want? What end result is "using jQuery" supposed to produce? Hover animations?

Comment: You have to add a lot more information and show some attempt to solve this. The question is not at all clear to me.

Comment: khez that are images. I need in text format also I want to integrate the navigation into joomla. and my client add and delete the menu item from joomla backend. how can i do this?
thanks for quick response.

Comment: Have you tried to make this work? At all ?

Comment: no, because I'm weak in math. I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Anyone know of a jQuery fisheye/dock navigation plugin that is able to have a fixed position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249903/anyone-know-of-a-jquery-fisheye-dock-navigation-plugin-that-is-able-to-have-a-fix)

As the answer to this other question suggests, use

http://www.ndesign-studio.com/blog/css-dock-menu

And change getPointer like this to allow for fixed positioning if you need it:

```
getPointer : function(event)
{
    var x = event.pageX || (event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft
            || document.body.scrollLeft)) || 0;
    var y = event.pageY || (event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop
            || document.body.scrollTop)) || 0;
    //subtract, add scrollbar    
    y -= $(window).scrollTop();
    return {x:x, y:y};
},
```